# binding variables to SQL statements using node-sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, binding, sqlite

I am trying to convert this:

```
var query_string = 'SELECT protein_A, protein_B, PIPE_score, site1_A_start FROM ' + organism + PIPE_output_table +
        ' WHERE ' + score_type + ' > ' + cutoff['range'] + ' AND protein_A = "' + item + '" ' +
        'UNION SELECT protein_A, protein_B, PIPE_score, site1_A_start FROM ' + organism + PIPE_output_table +
        ' WHERE ' + score_type + ' > ' + cutoff['range'] + ' AND protein_B = "' + item + '";';

 db.each(query_string, function (err, row) { 
  ...
```

To this:

```
var query_string = "SELECT protein_A, protein_B, PIPE_score, site1_A_start FROM $table WHERE $score_type > $score AND protein_A = '$protein'" +
        " UNION SELECT protein_A, protein_B, PIPE_score, site1_A_start FROM $table WHERE $score_type > $score AND protein_A = '$protein'";

    var placeholders = {
        $table: organism + PIPE_output_table,
        $score_type: score_type,
        $score: cutoff['range'],
        $protein: item
    };

    var stmt = db.prepare(query_string, placeholders, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        stmt.each(function(err,row) {
            ...
        })
    }
```

but I keep getting this error: 
Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "$table": syntax error

But I am not sure what is syntactically wrong here since the format is as I have seen it in the API documentation. I have tried '?', '@', and ':' before each variables but none seem to be recognized. 
What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind parameters only work for *values* in the `WHERE` clause.  Table and column names (collectively called "identifiers") won't work.

```
"SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE this = $that"    # OK

"SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE $this = 'that'"  # Not OK
```

Normally you'd work around this by escaping and quoting identifiers and inserting them into the query.  A good database library has a method call for this...

```
var this = db.quote_literal(input_column);
'SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE ' + this + ' = ?'
```

Unfortunately, node-sqlite3 doesn't appear to have one. :(

SQLite does provide a quoting function, [the %w operator](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_mprintf), but node-sqlite3 doesn't appear to make it available.

You'll have to write your own.  Follow the instructions from [this answer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6701665/14660) and convert them to Javascript.

- Ensure the string can be encoded as UTF-8.
- Ensure the string does not include any NUL characters.
- Replace all " with "".
- Wrap the entire thing in double quotes.

I'm not very good with Javascript, so I'll leave you to code that.

Comment: Oh I see, Thanks again for your help :)